# Embed fonts for flattend PDF form with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, pdf-form

I fill in a PDF form with PDFBox which I flatten before saving it. The form has a custom font for text and also form fields. When I open the output document (with flattened fields) on a device which does not have this custom font installed, the font of normal text is still correct, but the font of the flattened fields is displayed with a fallback (?) font. On a device which does have installed this custom font, everything looks as expected.

Is there a way to force using the same custom font for all text after flattening the form?

Code (simplified) used for filling in the PDF form with PDFBox:

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String formTemplate = "src/main/resources/fonts.pdf";
        String filledForm = "src/main/resources/fonts_out.pdf";
        PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(formTemplate));
        PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        acroForm.getField("text").setValue("Same font in form text field (updated with PDFBox)");
        acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);
        acroForm.refreshAppearances();
        acroForm.flatten();
        pdfDocument.save(filledForm);
        pdfDocument.close();
    }
}
```

PDFs:
[Input](https://www.mediafire.com/file/2fhsgzkbp7dtk3b/fonts.pdf/file)
[Output](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ikdecuj34ny99c7/fonts_out.pdf/file)

Expected:

[image: Expected]

Result when font is not installed on system:

[image: Result when font is not installed on system]

Comment: You might want to show some pivotal code and probably also share the pdf to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: @mkl: I've added code, PDFs and images of output to the question.

Comment: What kind of font is it? TrueType (TTF)? Type1 (AFM)?

Comment: @Lonzak: It's a TTF.

Comment: How did you add the form field? Is this a feature of libreOffice, too?

Comment: @Lonzak: Yes, you can create PDF forms with LibreOffice. It's basically the only free solution to create PDF forms (if you have a lot of time...) I've found so far. See for example http://foersom.com/org/HowTo/CreatePdfForm.html

Comment: @uwolfer I think I completely solved it, see update....

Comment: @Lonzak: Thank you very much for your time - it works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some observations for your PDF (the afore mentioned encoding problems are none - just plain ignorance on my behalf):

1. The SansDroid font is not embedded into the PDF. This is fixed by replacing the `F2` font with the newly embedded `F5` font.
2. The `NeedAppearances` flag is set meaning that there is no appearance for the form fields. Any reader must (re)create those. This is not done automatically by PDFBox before flattening so I added this part
3. To not cause any more warnings about missing fonts I removed the F2 font completely.
4. I run the original PDF through preflight and it gave me the following warning: "*The required key /Subtype is missing. Path: ->Pages->Kids->[0]->Annots->[0]->AP->N* " The key does exists however it seems to inicate that there is an error with the appearance of the form field. If I remove the /N dict the error is gone. The stream is "/Tx BMC EMC" - maybe there is some EOL missing? But since the appearance is regenerated anyway the error is gone afterwards.

With the following code the DroidSans font is embedded into the PDF:

```
File pdf = new File("Fonts.pdf");
final PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdf);

FileInputStream fontFile = new FileInputStream(new File("DroidSans.ttf"));
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, fontFile, false);

//1. embedd and register the font (Catalog dict)
PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
//create a new font resource
PDResources res = pDAcroForm.getDefaultResources();
if (res == null) res = new PDResources();
COSName fontName = res.add(font);
pDAcroForm.setDefaultResources(res);

//2. Now change the font of form field to the newly added font
PDField field = pDAcroForm.getField("text");
//field.setValue("Same font in form text field (updated with PDFBox)");

COSDictionary dict = field.getCOSObject();
COSString defaultAppearance = (COSString) dict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.DA);

if (defaultAppearance != null){
    String currentValue = dict.getString(COSName.DA);
    //replace the font - this should be improved with a more general version
    dict.setString(COSName.DA,currentValue.replace("F2", fontName.getName()));

    //remove F2 completely
    COSDictionary resources = res.getCOSObject();
    for(Entry<COSName, COSBase> resource : resources.entrySet()) {
        if(resource.getKey().equals(COSName.FONT)) {
            COSObject fonts = (COSObject)resource.getValue();
            COSDictionary fontDict = (COSDictionary)fonts.getObject();

            COSName toBeRemoved=null;
            for(Entry<COSName, COSBase> item : fontDict.entrySet()) {
                if(item.getKey().getName().equals("F2")) {
                    toBeRemoved = item.getKey();
                }
            }
            if(toBeRemoved!=null) {
                fontDict.removeItem(toBeRemoved);
            }
        }
    }

if(pDAcroForm.getNeedAppearances()) {
    pDAcroForm.refreshAppearances();
    pDAcroForm.setNeedAppearances(false);
}

//Flatten the document
pDAcroForm.flatten();

//Save the document
document.save("Form-Test-Result.pdf");
document.close();
```

**Please note that the above code is quite static - Searching and replacing a font called `F2` only works for the supplied PDF in other cases it won't. You have to implement a more generic solution for that...**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your investigations! The encoding issue is really strange - it's a simple document created with LibreOffice PDF export. Anyway, I have tried your code and I think it works as expected. I use for testing https://www.pdfpro.co/pdf-viewer (which only produces expected results when font is properly embedded). The "F2" font name i interesting - I just wonder why it works this way on systems which have installed the Droid Sans font...

Comment: *"FEFF is supposed to be the UTF-16 BOM. This is in my opinion quite strange to do it in this way"* - please explain why it is strange. It may be unnecessary for the contents at hand but not per se incorrect.

Comment: Because in my understanding the [BOM](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) must be quote: "encoded in the same scheme as the rest of the document" (or as in our case as the rest of the string). The BOM is a unicode character `U+FEFF`BYTE sequence which are only allowed to be used as a BOM. As you can see in the table (cp. above wikilink) the FEFF is the hexadecimal representation (254 255 decimal or `þÿ` in 1252). The content of the strings are totally different characters. HEX= 46 45 46 46 (same decimal and FEFF in 1252). This is ascii and thus not a valid BOM.

Comment: "_please explain why it is strange. It may be unnecessary for the contents at hand but not per se incorrect._" On the contrary it is quite important for the interpretation of the content! But a valid BOM should be used and not ANSI encoded characters. I mean how does you differentiate if I write ["FEFFERNITZ"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feffernitz) into a textfield - does this mean I want to start a UTF-16 string and the rest should be interpreted as UTF-16? No...

Comment: @uwolfer "_The "F2" font name i interesting - I just wonder why it works this way on systems which have installed the Droid Sans font..._" The F2 font is a valid font definition but bascially only references the system font (cp. objects 12 0 and 13 0 in the original PDF). If the font exists everything is fine but if not the reference is invalid and e.g. *dobe Reader triggers an error when editing the field (Font DroidSans is missing...)

Comment: It obviously is a hex-encoded string, see the angled brackets. Thus, `FEFF005300...` represents the byte sequence 0xfe, 0xff, 0x00, 0x53, 0x00, ... So there's nothing strange here...

Comment: @mkl Ah you are right! I missed (honestly didn't know :-) the angle brackets syntax. According to the spec: "_Strings may also be written in hexadecimal form, which is useful for including arbitrary binary data in a PDF file. A hexadecimal string shall be written as a sequence of hexadecimal digits (0–9 and either A–F or a–f) encoded as ASCII characters and enclosed within angle brackets (using LESS-THAN SIGN (3Ch) and GREATER-THAN SIGN (3Eh))._" Now that mystery is solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

> `PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, fontFile, false);`

I thing that the last argument ('false') embed all characters in a font.
That make a heavy size pdf when using a large font like Japanese fonts.
So, I tried the following code and it worked for me.

(* Scala, PDFBox 2.0.20)

```
// val font = PDType0Font.load(document, fontFile, true);
// form.flatten()

// hack for embed minimul font?
val page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A6) // any page size.
val stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)
stream.beginText()
stream.setFont(font, 0)
stream.showText(allChars) // `allChars` are inputed all characters in forms in the creating pdf.
stream.endText()
stream.close()
// NOTE: I did NOT add the page to the PDF but worked.  

// Save the document ~
```

Comment: The original question was about acroform, there it is better to subset. Your code is for ordinary text, and it is OK, but only there.