# Can I embed a subset of font for a pdf file with a flattened acroform using PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I fill in a PDF form with PDFBox and flatten it. It only works when the font was fully embeded, but the file's size is too large. Is there any way can I embed a subset of the font?

Similar scene: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53968324/embed-fonts-for-flattend-pdf-form-with-pdfbox)

I want to embed a subset of font into the PDF file.